# iOS: WeChat custom schema?

Tags: ios, schema, wechat

I am implementing an app that needs to switch to WeChat (a Chinese IM app) inside my app. I can do this using the wechat schema `weixin://`, however, does anyone have any idea how can I switch directly to the chatting window with a specific user if I have the his wechat userId?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that, Tencent does not allow this request.

you can just call wechat api encapsulate the content that you want to send. and pick the user manually.

the reason is the userId you specified maybe not in in the user's account. (WeChat request user to be friends first, then they can chat each other).

Hope it is clear!

You can check the WeChat Official Share Logic:
http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi

Section: Sharing via WeChat Message